# Java (jre) doesn't work anymore, even eclipse won't startup

Tags: windows, java, local, jre, appdata

I have tried to change my java version.I wanted version 14.0.1. There is a version 1.8.0.145, it's still there in a dir in program files.
But now, when type java -version in cmd, it's looking for 'jre1.8.0_261\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'. This file is in 'C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Search_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\AppIconCache\100' ... What do i do with it ???

Comment: How did you try to update java?

Answer (score 0):

I think you used the old (java 8) updater which cannot change your Java version (only downloads patches). This is intentional, as java 8 is an LTS version, and it is (was) updated while other java releases rolled out.

To fix this issue, you have to download java 14 from the official website, and if the downloaded installer doesn't fix the issue, you need to edit some environmental variables as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation

Also, why is your java not in Program Files?